# How to embed arguments into Robot Framework keyword name

Tags: keyword, robotframework

I've tried to make some keywords in Robot Framework which has arguments embedded in the keyword name, according to ([Robot Docs)](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/userguide/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#embedding-arguments-into-keyword-name), but unfortunately I'm always getting `None` when I'm checking what is under the variable. Did you meet such behaviour? What have I done wrong??

My keyword example:

```
Set ${object} state to ${state}
    Log To Console  ${object}
    Log To Console  ${state}
```

Let's assume that ${object} and ${state} are strings, so the call of this keyword looks like this:

```
${status}=  Run Keyword And Return Status  Set camera state to locked
```

Comment: Your code looks good and I cannot reproduce your problem. I got True to ${status}. log.html should show you if your keyword does not return proper status. Can you modify your code to include both full testcase and full keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is fine. Here is a complete working example:

```
*** Keywords ***
Set ${object} state to ${state}
    Log To Console    ${object}
    Log To Console    ${state}

*** Test Cases ***
Example test case
    ${status}=        Run Keyword And Return Status    Set camera state to locked
    Should be True    ${status}
```